# How Do Rails Controllers Share Instance Variables with Views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am fairly new to Rails, but I am pretty experienced with Ruby. Can somebody tell me how Rails makes instance variables from a controller available to views. How did the Rails team go about implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would take a lot of digging through the rails source to figure it out for sure, but I believe it's mostly done using the standard Ruby ['binding'](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Binding.html) stuff.

Comment: Ok thanks that was the kind of general answer I was looking for.